# Mongodb : Add conditions into an array update

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to know more how conditions works on mongodb. In my case, I've got an $addToSet operators :

```
$addToSet: {
    $dateToString: {
        "date": "$contributions.validationDate",
        "format": "%d.%m.%Y",
    }
}
```

My goal is to only $addToSet if $contributions.validationDate exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can try something like this :

```
// Assuming $addToSet is being used in $group, not sure where exactly you're using it.

db.yourCollection.aggregate([{
    $group:
    {
        _id: null,
        uniqueDates: {
            $addToSet: { $dateToString: { format: "%d.%m.%Y", date: "$contributions.validationDate", onNull: '$noVal' } }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Whole point in here - All you need is `onNull: '$noVal'`, which would avoid adding `null` if `contributions.validationDate` is missing.

**Ref :** [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html#example)